# WHM / cPanel - Disable PHP Send Mail For One Account

Tags: php, sendmail, cpanel, whm

I currently have a WHM / cPanel server, and a particular user keeps having their WordPress compromised and used to send out spam. I am looking to disable the ability for this one account to send email out via PHP.

After looking around, I saw recommendations to go into `WHM -> Tweak Settings -> Disable "nobody" from sending mail`, however that doesn't help me as I am using suPHP.

The other recommendation was to manually add `disabled_functions = mail` to the `php.ini` file, but of course that would block all users from being able to send mail.

Is anyone able to recommend a way of doing this, either within `php.ini` or WHM / cPanel itself? Thanks!

Comment: Pragmatic solution: If this user's site keeps on getting compromised, they need to identify and fix the vulnerability, or you need to stop hosting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the separate php.ini file for your user and disable the mail function in that php.ini file,

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Where exactly would I place the `php.ini`?

Comment: You would place that php.ini file in user's public_html/ folder. For examle if the cpanel user is let's say: abcd then you will place php.ini file in /home/abcd/public_html

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to disable php mail function as: `mail, sendmail`
by **WHM** => **PHP Configuration Editor** =>**Advanced Mode**  => **disable_functions**

Now after that enable by php.ini on only that account who are trusted and other will be auto disabled by default.
i hope this will be better.